# system() call always fail with -1

Tags: system

I have a process which returns always -1 on `system()` call, but other processes on the same system do not have this error. I'm clueless to why this process is always returning -1 on the `system()` call. The command with which the `system()` is invoked is also successful. It just that it always returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) for that process. 
When SIGCHLD is ignored, then waipid should not be called after a fork.
But it looks like system call always call waitpid and this will cause the system to return -1.

```
#include  <signal.h>
#include  <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    int ret = 0;
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

    ret =  system("echo hello!!");
    printf("ret=%d errno=%d error=%s\n",ret,errno,strerror(errno));

}
```

---

```
bash-3.2$ ./a.out 
hello!!
ret=-1 errno=10 error=No child processes
bash-3.2$
```